# R Shiny Server Error Download Markdown PDF ! LaTeX Error: File `threeparttablex.sty' not found

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, rstudio-server

I recently started experiencing an issue with multiple Shiny applications that generate R markdown PDF documents via download buttons.  All of them generate tables using kable() and kable_styling() from the kableExtra package, and they were all working flawlessly until recently. Now, the first press of the download button will fail to download the report. If you press the button again, it works.

If I log into my company's RStudio Connect server and view the log, I can locate the entry for the error on the first button press:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `threeparttablex.sty' not found.
08/17 18:52:51.399 (GMT)
! Emergency stop.
08/17 18:52:51.399 (GMT)
<read *>
08/17 18:52:51.402 (GMT)
Warning: Error in : LaTeX failed to compile /opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/tmp/RtmpM18u7T/file7dcdd4a7e3ae8.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See file7dcdd4a7e3ae8.log for more info.
```

Here's my YAML header for the .Rmd file:

```
---
title: "title"
output: pdf_document
header-includes: 
   \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   \usepackage{float}
   \pagestyle{fancy} 
   \fancyhead[L]{`r params$docNum`}
   \fancyhead[C]{`r params$attachNum`}
   \fancyhead[R]{Report Date `r Sys.Date()`}
   \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
   \fancyfoot[C]{footer text}
   \AtBeginDocument{\let\maketitle\relax}
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
params:
  inputs: NA
  power: NA
  docNum: NA
  attachNum: NA
---
```

And here's the code chunk for the table:

```
df = params$inputs

df %>% kable(align='cc', format="latex") %>% row_spec(0, bold=TRUE) %>% kable_styling(latex_options = "HOLD_position")
```

Since the problem started occurring on multiple apps, some of which have not been updated recently, could it be a regression error with a server update?  The problem does not happen when running locally.  Any ideas for a workaround?  Thanks.

Below is most of the text of one of the logs.  Some entries are redacted, but all relevant details should be there.

```
2022/08/16 23:13:40.621159053 Linux distribution: Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)
2022/08/16 23:13:40.621187277 Server version: 2022.05.0
2022/08/16 23:13:40.621236478 LANG: en_US.UTF-8
2022/08/16 23:13:40.621315722 Working directory: /opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/app
2022/08/16 23:13:40.622039670 Running content using its packrat R library
2022/08/16 23:13:40.678391327 Using Packrat dir /opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/app/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.2.0
2022/08/16 23:13:40.692397440 R version: 4.2.0
2022/08/16 23:13:40.692409417 shiny version: 1.7.1
2022/08/16 23:13:40.692428504 httpuv version: 1.6.5
2022/08/16 23:13:40.692451960 rmarkdown version: 2.14
2022/08/16 23:13:40.692464308 knitr version: 1.39
2022/08/16 23:13:40.692521462 jsonlite version: 1.8.0
2022/08/16 23:13:40.692526564 RJSONIO version: (none)
2022/08/16 23:13:40.692561850 htmltools version: 0.5.2
2022/08/16 23:13:40.692576277 reticulate version: (none)
2022/08/16 23:13:40.692822388 Using pandoc: /opt/rstudio-connect/ext/pandoc/2.16
2022/08/16 23:13:41.081473306 Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2022/08/16 23:13:41.085340113 Using Shiny bookmarking base directory /opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/bookmarks
2022/08/16 23:13:41.085576000 
2022/08/16 23:13:41.085591088 Starting R with process ID: '510456'
2022/08/16 23:13:41.086031098 Shiny application starting ...
2022/08/16 23:13:41.150073754 
2022/08/16 23:13:41.150084918 Attaching package: ‘shinyjs’
2022/08/16 23:13:41.150133560 
2022/08/16 23:13:41.150723688 The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:
2022/08/16 23:13:41.150731839 
2022/08/16 23:13:41.150752714     runExample
2022/08/16 23:13:41.150758183 
2022/08/16 23:13:41.151013087 The following objects are masked from ‘package:methods’:
2022/08/16 23:13:41.151021527 
2022/08/16 23:13:41.151041274     removeClass, show
2022/08/16 23:13:41.151044798 
2022/08/16 23:13:41.878988529 
2022/08/16 23:13:41.879003918 Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
2022/08/16 23:13:41.879040092 
2022/08/16 23:13:41.879340055 The following objects are masked from ‘package:data.table’:
2022/08/16 23:13:41.879348537 
2022/08/16 23:13:41.879364473     between, first, last
2022/08/16 23:13:41.879366255 
2022/08/16 23:13:41.879636271 The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
2022/08/16 23:13:41.879643131 
2022/08/16 23:13:41.879658496     filter, lag
2022/08/16 23:13:41.879660411 
2022/08/16 23:13:41.879945558 The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
2022/08/16 23:13:41.879956835 
2022/08/16 23:13:41.879999703     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
2022/08/16 23:13:41.879999703 
2022/08/16 23:13:42.066010805 
2022/08/16 23:13:42.066025975 Listening on http://127....
2022/08/16 23:40:04.729421935 processing file: report.Rmd
2022/08/16 23:40:04.750732112 
  |                                                                            
  |                                                                      |   0%
  |                                                                            
  |..............                                                        |  20%
2022/08/16 23:40:04.750972879    inline R code fragments
2022/08/16 23:40:04.750981585 
2022/08/16 23:40:04.753104689 
  |                                                                            
  |............................                                          |  40%
2022/08/16 23:40:04.754435440 label: setup (with options) 
2022/08/16 23:40:04.757149131 List of 1
2022/08/16 23:40:04.758069301  $ include: logi FALSE
2022/08/16 23:40:04.758117631 
2022/08/16 23:40:04.952992184 
  |                                                                            
  |..........................................                            |  60%
2022/08/16 23:40:04.953039222   ordinary text without R code
2022/08/16 23:40:04.953043571 
2022/08/16 23:40:04.953190479 
  |                                                                            
  |........................................................              |  80%
2022/08/16 23:40:04.953667027 label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 
2022/08/16 23:40:04.953887403 List of 2
2022/08/16 23:40:04.954599108  $ echo   : logi FALSE
2022/08/16 23:40:04.955152760  $ results: chr "asis"
2022/08/16 23:40:04.955217206 
2022/08/16 23:40:04.975045837 
  |                                                                            
  |......................................................................| 100%
2022/08/16 23:40:04.975104631    inline R code fragments
2022/08/16 23:40:04.975113733 
2022/08/16 23:40:04.976269863 
2022/08/16 23:40:04.976804936 output file: report.knit.md
2022/08/16 23:40:04.976811946 
2022/08/16 23:40:04.982490875 /opt/rstudio-connect/ext/pandoc/2.16/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS report.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output /opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/tmp/RtmpN4ih69/file7c9f83f020195.tex --lua-filter /opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/packrat/4.2.0/v2/library/rmarkdown/cc514dae1dc452ec2ffd6d170a462b27/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/packrat/4.2.0/v2/library/rmarkdown/cc514dae1dc452ec2ffd6d170a462b27/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --include-in-header /opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/tmp/RtmpN4ih69/rmarkdown-str7c9f87b29aa3.html --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' --include-in-header /opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/tmp/RtmpN4ih69/rmarkdown-str7c9f85a4f1d1f.html 
2022/08/16 23:40:05.230413483 ! LaTeX Error: File `threeparttablex.sty' not found.
2022/08/16 23:40:05.230426416 
2022/08/16 23:40:05.230458062 ! Emergency stop.
2022/08/16 23:40:05.230463687 <read *> 
2022/08/16 23:40:05.230466903 
2022/08/16 23:40:05.232558162 Warning: Error in : LaTeX failed to compile /opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/tmp/RtmpN4ih69/file7c9f83f020195.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See file7c9f83f020195.log for more info.
2022/08/16 23:40:05.237383668   [No stack trace available]
2022/08/16 23:40:07.491929273 
2022/08/16 23:40:07.526957743 
2022/08/16 23:40:07.526969314 
2022/08/16 23:40:07.527002957 processing file: report.Rmd
2022/08/16 23:40:07.530474230 
  |                                                                            
  |                                                                      |   0%
  |                                                                            
  |..............                                                        |  20%
2022/08/16 23:40:07.530547565    inline R code fragments
2022/08/16 23:40:07.530557189 
2022/08/16 23:40:07.531704015 
  |                                                                            
  |............................                                          |  40%
2022/08/16 23:40:07.532260821 label: setup (with options) 
2022/08/16 23:40:07.532547453 List of 1
2022/08/16 23:40:07.533362326  $ include: logi FALSE
2022/08/16 23:40:07.533410226 
2022/08/16 23:40:07.543254592 
  |                                                                            
  |..........................................                            |  60%
2022/08/16 23:40:07.543308845   ordinary text without R code
2022/08/16 23:40:07.543319594 
2022/08/16 23:40:07.543449383 
  |                                                                            
  |........................................................              |  80%
2022/08/16 23:40:07.543957217 label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 
2022/08/16 23:40:07.544151165 List of 2
2022/08/16 23:40:07.544823050  $ echo   : logi FALSE
2022/08/16 23:40:07.545338225  $ results: chr "asis"
2022/08/16 23:40:07.545367461 
2022/08/16 23:40:07.561593854 
  |                                                                            
  |......................................................................| 100%
2022/08/16 23:40:07.561652341    inline R code fragments
2022/08/16 23:40:07.561661055 
2022/08/16 23:40:07.562346452 
2022/08/16 23:40:07.562694155 output file: report.knit.md
2022/08/16 23:40:07.562701953 
2022/08/16 23:40:07.566077948 /opt/rstudio-connect/ext/pandoc/2.16/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS report.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output /opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/tmp/RtmpN4ih69/file7c9f87897ecb1.tex --lua-filter /opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/packrat/4.2.0/v2/library/rmarkdown/cc514dae1dc452ec2ffd6d170a462b27/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/packrat/4.2.0/v2/library/rmarkdown/cc514dae1dc452ec2ffd6d170a462b27/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --include-in-header /opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/tmp/RtmpN4ih69/rmarkdown-str7c9f825c4e9d1.html --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' 
2022/08/16 23:40:08.119471472 
2022/08/16 23:40:08.119476730 Output created: /opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/tmp/RtmpN4ih69/file7c9f87897ecb1.pdf
2022/08/17 00:42:54.010170903 [rsc-session] Received signal: interrupt
2022/08/17 00:42:54.010195999 [rsc-session] Terminating subprocess with SIGINT ...
2022/08/17 00:42:54.020537199 
2022/08/17 00:42:54.020599720 
2022/08/17 00:42:54.022139380 Shiny application exiting ...
2022/08/17 00:42:54.022171284 Execution halted
2022/08/17 00:42:54.057547463 [rsc-session] Terminated subprocess with signal: interrupt
```

Comment: Can you post what the .log output is in your output console message?

Comment: @Daniel_j_iii, I just added the log to the end of my post.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by installing files manually: downloaded from CTAN and copied to /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ , each of them in their own package name (using REDHAT, could be different in other systems).

So, I've got:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/threeparttablex:
threeparttablex.pdf
threeparttablex.sty
threeparttablex.tex

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecell:
makecell.dtx
makecell.pdf
makecell-rus.pdf
makecell-rus.tex
makecell.sty (this one from another source --> https://gitlab.cs.washington.edu/blank/texmf/blob/1247153a1c68e3dddbc20e3e907569812b3849b5/tex/latex/makecell.sty)
```

Then, executed the command **mktexlsr** to refresh the libraries/packages and that's it! Hope it works for you too.